# vsftpd chmod upload permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, chmod, vsftpd

I have vsftpd 2.3.2-3.

After user uploaded a file it has `-rw-------(0600)` permissions. Of course user can change permissions manually to anything he likes.

But how to set for example `0700` by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a setting in the vsftpd.conf file:

> **file_open_mode**
>
> The permissions with which uploaded files are created. Umasks are applied on top of this value. You may wish to change to 0777 if you want uploaded files to be executable.
>
> **Default:** 0666

Simply change the mode to 0777, then with the umask added you get 0700

Ref: http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html

Comment: o! chown_upload_mode - what i need. I will not be lazy to man another time =) thanks